# Need help writing a Cassandra UDF function

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-functions, cassandra-3.0

Need help writing a cassandra udf to add/divide/multiply two variable. Tried the below code however it doesn't seem to work. Also I have no experience in java, so may be I am not able to debug. Help appreciated on this.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_adder(val1 double,val2 double )
    RETURNS double LANGUAGE java
    BODY
        return (val1 == null || val2 == null)?null:Double.valueOf( val1.doubleValue() + val2.doubleValue());
    END BODY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null inputs should be handled either using `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` or `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` as documented [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateFunction.html).

So in this case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_adder(val1 double,val2 double )
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 'return val1 + val2;';
```

Testing it:

```
create table mytable(
p int,
foo double,
bar double,
primary key (p));

insert into mytable (p, foo, bar)
values (0, 1.0, 2.0);
insert into mytable (p, foo, bar)
values (1, NULL, 2.0);
insert into mytable (p, foo, bar)
values (2, 1.0, NULL);

select p,my_adder(foo, bar) from mytable;

 p | test.my_adder(foo, bar)
---+---------------------------------
 1 |                            null
 0 |                               3
 2 |                            null
```

Comment: Works , Thank you